# Configuring spree with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am getting error while running `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:bootstrap`. Can anybody show me the best way to overcome this error?

```
rake aborted!
undefined method 'set_preference' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without a few more details (rails version? rvm or not?); I would always start checking whether the correct rails version is accessible and whether 'bundle install' was done.